# How can one find the value of x such that $\left(1-\sqrt{1-(R-1)^2}\right)-\left(1-R^{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)^{2-x}=0$, $(0<R<1)$?

Tags: geometry, roots, problem-solving

How can one find the value of x such that $\left(1-\sqrt{1-(R-1)^2}\right)-\left(1-R^{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)^{2-x}=0$, $(0<R<1)$?

some ideas so far are:

Choosing $R=0.5$,

$$0.133975\, -\left(1-0.5^{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)^{2-x}=0$$

This would leave expanding the power $2-x$, but then it is unclear how to proceed.

Is there a method/technique to determine if this is possible without approximating $x\approx0.222052962563297$

Comment: This is equivalent to solving $a^x+b^x=1$ which often does not have a closed form.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I see

Comment: r=x=2 is a solution.

Comment: Another option is to transform it into a trinomial and solving via its [series solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial)

Comment: @Тyma Gaidash thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\left(1-\sqrt{1-(R-1)^2}\right)-\left(1-R^{\frac{1}{2-x}}\right)^{2-x}$$
Computing
$$f(0) >0 \qquad \text{and}\qquad f'(0)<0 $$

The first iterate of Newton method using $x_0=0$ is
$$x_1=\frac{2 \left(R-2 \sqrt{R}+\sqrt{-((R-2)
   R)}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{R}-1\right) \left(2
   \left(\sqrt{R}-1\right) \log \left(1-\sqrt{R}\right)-\sqrt{R}   \log (R)\right)}$$

For most of the range of $R$ (above $R=0.04$) $$f(0) \times f''(0) <0$$ So, by Darboux theorem, the first iterate is known to be an over estimate of the solution (for $R=0.5$ we have $x_1=0.272$ but the convergence will be quite fast

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.0000000000 \\
 1 & 0.2720666384 \\
 2 & 0.2240447216 \\
 3 & 0.2220562559 \\
 4 & 0.2220529626 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: unexpected after three years but welcome. thank you for answering the question.